# Choice of a primary key in SQL table

Tags: database, primary-key-design

I want to make an SQL table to keep track of notes that are added/edited/deleted. I want to be able to display the state of each `NOTEID` at this moment in a table, display log of changes of selected note and be able to delete all notes marked with a given `NOTEID`.

```
create table[dbo].[NOTES]{
  NOTEID [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
  CREATEDBY [varchar](128) NOT NULL, /*is this redundant?*/
  TIMECREATED  DATE NOT NULL,          /*is this redundant?*/
  MODIFIEDBY [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
  TIMEMODIFIED  DATE NOT NULL,
  NOTE [VARCHAR}(2000) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( /* undecided */ ),
};
```

What is the natural way of making this table? Should I autogenerate the primary ID or should I use (`NOTEID`,`TIMEMODIFIED`) as the primary key? What kind of fool proof protection should be added?

---

I would like to be able to display all notes in a "Note history" window. So, I should store note from 3 days ago, when it was created, note from 2 days ago and from today, when it was modified.

However, the "Notes" table will show the final state for each NOTEID. That is

```
SELECT NOTE from NOTES where NOTEID = 'selected_note_id' and date = latest
```

Comment: I think your createdby and timecreated are redundant. The record with the earliest timemodified value would be the time created.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is create two tables.

```
 NOTES (
     NOTE_ID        -- primary key and autogenerated / autonumeric
     CREATEDBY      -- only appear once
     TIMECREATED    -- only appear once
     NOTE 
 )

 NOTES_UPDATE (
     NOTES_UPDATE_ID   -- primary key and autogenerated / autonumeric
     NOTE_ID           -- Foreign Key to NOTES
     MODIFIEDBY 
     TIMEMODIFIED  
     NOTE 
 )
```

You can get your notes updates

```
 SELECT N.*, NU.*
 FROM NOTES N
 JOIN NOTES_UPDATE NU
   ON N.NOTE_ID = NU.NOTE_ID
```

and to get the last update just add

```
 ORDER BY NOTE_UPDATE_ID DESC
 LIMIT 1   -- THIS is postgres sintaxis.
```

Comment: If you are duplicating the `NOTE` in both of your tables, you  might as well just have one table which can have multiple notes.

Comment: I like this. In fact, that's how I do it too. Your primary key is also your your foreign key in the history table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You need multiple table because in the first one you get the `NOTE_ID` from autonumeric for new notes. In the second one you reference that one. Also you only save the original `NOTE` there.

Answer (score 1):

I think your current table design is fine, though you might want to make the `NOTEID` the primary key and auto increment it.  I don't see the point of making `(NOTEID, TIMEMODIFIED)` a composite primary key because a given note ID should ideally only appear once in the table.  If the modified time changes, the ID should remain the same.

Assuming we treat notes as files on a computer, then there should be only one table (file system) which stores them.  If a given note gets modified, then the timestamp changes to reflect this.

Comment: They probably want some kind of audit table, where you can track `NOTE` changes over time, that is why you may need a PK separated from `NOTE_ID`

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE ANSWER:**

The `PRIMARY KEY` should be the value that unique identifies each row in your table. In your particular case, `NOTEID` should be your id.

**ELABORATING:**

It is important to remember that a `PRIMARY KEY` creates an index by default, which means that whenever you do a query similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOTEID = something
```

The query will execute a lot faster than without an index (which is mostly relevant for bigger tables). The `PRIMARY KEY` is also forced to be unique, hence no two rows can have the same `PRIMARY KEY`

A general rule is that you should have an `INDEX` for any value that will often be used within the `WHERE ...` part of the statement. If `NOTEID` is not the only value you will be using in the `WHERE ....` part of the query, consider creating more indexes

HOWEVER! TREAD WITH CAUTION. Indexes help speed up searches with `SELECT` however they make `UPDATE` and `INSERT` work slower.